# Getting Keys from ValueProvider in ModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have an AJAX request from client-side which POSTs json objects to my ASP.NET MVC 4 server, resulting in populated **DictionaryValueProvider<object>** within **ValueProvider**. 
Now, I dont't know all field names beforehand (there is dynamic fields adding ability on client-side), so I need to pack them in some sort of Dictionary in my custom ModelBinder (derived from **DefaultModelBinder**).

I can't get values from **controllerContext** form values or query string, neither from **DictionaryValueProvider** directly without knowing the key in **IValueProvider.GetValue(Key)**.

How can I access all keys from ValueProvider in my ModelBinder then?

Answer (score -2):

As you say, the ValueProvider requires the key to get a value, but you can access all keys via the controllerContext of a custom model binder using **controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys** if that's of any use.

e.g.

```
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
            string[] allKeys = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually can't get all keys via controllerContext. For some reason, needed keys are not presented in controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKey

Comment: This isn't correct. It doesn't take into account route values for instance which are not found here.